# Can't import pygame even though it is installed

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, pygame, python-idle

I go into IDLE and type in import pygame to the shell and it gives me an error. Then I go into a new program and type in import pygame and I get the same error. I installed pygame with pip and are using python 3, version 3.6.8.

I have tried reinstalling pygame and trying to install in with sudo.
I also have tried using pip3, same result.

```
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import pygame
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'
>>>
```

Comment: Can you please query `pip3` to see if PyGame is installed:  `pip3 list --format=legacy | grep -i game`.  When I run this, I get: 
`pygame (1.9.4.dev0)`.  If you're on windows, just run the first part (before the `|`) and search the list of installed packages yourself.

Comment: Just to clarify this:  Currently on Linux, using `pip` installs the package for Python version 2.x.  You must use `pip3` to install for Python version 3.x.  I suspect PyGame was accidentally installed *only* for Python2.7, and not for Python3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had to use 'pip3' and not just 'pip'. Thanks to everybody who helped.

Answer (score 1):

If you have pip installed, inside the terminal you should be doing:

```
pip install pygame
```

Also, make sure you actually have pip installed.. https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/install-pip-for-python/
Hope that helps, if it works, please mark my question as the answer. Good luck with your py-games. Welcome to the community!